# 手を出す -- how to use it?

Tags: word-choice, colloquial-language

I have learnt 手を出す　from watching Anime. In the context it was 子供に手を出したりしないわよ (if I heard correctly) and it means that she wouldn't make a move on a child.

> Can I use this word without any sexual connotation?

For example, can I use it to say I don't really use Facebook in the following way:

Facebookにあまり手を出さない。

Or is it unnatural and the proper way to say this is

Facebookをあまり使わない。

Hm... or perhaps I'm getting the verb tense wrong and it should be

Facebookをあまり使っていない。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「手を出す」has several meanings and it depends on the situation it is used.

「手を出す」

- けんかをする(暴力を振るう)
- some sexual meanings..
- touch or interact (ex: 「Facebookに手を出す」)
- 手をさし出す(show someones hand) (ex: 「アメをあげるから、手を出して」(Want candys? Show me your hand.))

女性の場合は「子供に手をあげる」(子供をたたく、あるいは、暴力を振るう)などの表現も使います。

「手を出さない」

- けんかをしない(暴力を振るわない)
- some sexual meanings..
- will not touch or interact (ex: 「Facebookにあまり手を出さない」)

---

> Facebookにあまり手を出さない。
>   Facebookをあまり使わない。
>   Facebookをあまり使っていない。

全て、使えると思います。

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Just to be sure: are you a native speaker?

Comment: Ya. I'm a native speaker.